# Please tell me what is wrong with this HAML :sass filter syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

```
-content_for :styles do
  :sass
    #image_column { 
      width: 200px;
      float: right;
      padding:15px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
```

error: Invalid CSS after "200px": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"

Comment: In addition to stef's answer, read this: [SCSS: CSS-style syntax for SASS](http://thechangelog.com/post/318521329/scss-css-style-syntax-for-sass).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've written SCSS instead of SASS. Try this?

```
- content_for :styles do
  :sass
    #image_column 
      width: 200px
      float: right
      padding: 15px
      background-color: #eee
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem using [SCOUT](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/) and naming files **example.sass**

Same error:

> expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";")

Because i forgot change extension to **.scss**

Maybe this will be helpful.